# Fail if a script expects input or entering passwords

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm developing a script that should not need interaction with the user, and if a program inside my script needs the user to enter something, the script should fail and exit immediately.

I have already closed the `STDIN` at the top of my script, and this works for some commands, but there are some that expect the input in another file descriptor (usually the ones asking for passwords like `git` or `sudo`).

Currently my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# close STDIN
exec 0<&-

# test that $1 exists and it is a valid folder containing a git repository
# ...

cd "$1"

git fetch
# if git is not correctly configured, it asks for a password and
# my script waits for it :(
```

So, how can I avoid this?

note: I'm not asking how to do a password-less config in `git` or `sudo` or `whatever`, but to prevent a program in `bash` (or `sh`) to expect user input and fail immediately if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to close standard input or standard error, you might be better off just using a short expect script that bails out if it sees a password prompt. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"

expect -c '
    log_user 0
    spawn git fetch
    expect -timeout 30 -re "ass(phrase|word)" { exit 1 }
    '

# Do something based on the exit status of the expect script.
[[ $? -eq 1 ]] && { echo 'Password prompt detected!' >&2; exit 1; }
```

The expect script will return with exit status 1 if it sees a password or key passphrase prompt. The bash script is then free to do likewise, or to take other action.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But what would happen if the command outputs some text containing those words?

Comment: Expect will terminate the git-fetch process, which is what you said you wanted. You can always tweak your regex if it's too greedy or not matching your particular prompts, but I can't imagine a scenario where you will get a false positive from git-fetch unless your repository is named "passwords" or similar.

Comment: Sorry, then it is not valid for me, I'd like a more generic answer because the executed programs (not always `git fetch`) can output whatever, and I want the script to work whatever the output is, just fail if the command is waiting for input. Have un upvote though :)

Comment: Well, 2 days past the original question and I can't find any answer better than what you suggested, so I'm going this way

Answer (score 3):

First let me say that I don't think this is the right way to approach your problem.  At all.  There has to be a better application-specific solution and you really should find it.

The main problem is that without knowing what programs you want to "force close" you won't know how to cause them to "error out".  And if you *do* know the programs, CodeGnome's solution seems fine.

Also note that not all programs read input directly from STDIN.  For example, Python's getpass module opens up an additional file descriptor directly to `/dev/tty`, so closing or redirecting STDIN doesn't matter.  This is also how `sudo` accepts passwords and I believe this is how ncurses works as well.  Reading in this manner allows you to get passwords without them being displayed on the screen.

For prompts that don't read directly from `/dev/tty` (e.g. bash's `read`) simply redirecting STDIN from `/dev/null` (e.g. `./prompt.sh </dev/null`) might get you somewhere.  Alternatively, you could do what you're doing and close STDIN, ***but how the program behaves when it encounters a closed STDIN or a redirected one consisting only of EOFs is out of your control.***  Hopefully, the program would error out as you wish, but maybe it would continue to loop, expecting valid input.  Who knows?

Moreover, neither closing nor redirecting will globally be the way that works, if either does.  Some programs may exit out as you hope for closed STDINs, others may need the EOFs from `/dev/null`

So the way to do this is not a general, catch-all type of solution, but one tailored to the programs that you put in that spot.  Better yet, don't use a **try** (to run the program), then **catch** (the case where the program asks for input) method, simply call the programs in ways that ***you know*** they won't ask for input.

Anyway, all that being said, one possibility that might work is to close STDIN and background the process.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 0<&-
./prompt.sh &
```

or alternatively, redirect STDIN to /dev/null and background the process.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

./prompt.sh </dev/null &
```

You would then need to check the return code of the programs (with `$?`) to see whether they exited correctly.  (Hopefully the unknown list of programs you're using follows the standard return value scheme)

The closing / redirecting of STDIN will handle the case where STDIN is used to accept input and backgrounding the process will handle the case where `/dev/tty` is (since a backgrounded process doesn't have a tty).

You're on your own if the program prompts you using some other method (opens up an FD directly to your pseudoterminal, pops up a graphical input box, presents you with an audible prompt, etc. etc.).

Comment: I tried executing the program in background, but it didn't work also (it got blocked until I `fg` it and then it asked for a pass. I guess I'll have to do what @CodeGnome proposed and use `expect`. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Simply running it in the background isn't sufficient, you also need to either close (or redirect) STDIN, did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Most (all?) *NIX have a `tty` command which prints out the name of the shell's `tty` and exits `0` if the shell has a tty attached, else it exits `1` error.

```
if ! tty>&/dev/null; then echo "Not a terminal; goodbye."; exit 1; fi
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The script will be launched interactively by a user, so there always will be a controlling tty