# fail on git password challenge during cronjob bash script

Tags: git, bash, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I am running the following bash script as a cron job:

```
    #!/bin/bash


    gh[1]="https://github.com/myteam/myrepo1"
    gh[2]="https://github.com/myteam/myrepo2"
    gh[3]="https://github.com/myteam/myrepo3"

    for index in ${!gh[*]}
    do
    git clone ${gh[$index]} ./src
    done
```

some of the repos do not exist OR are password protected.  I have looked at a few options:

a. upgrade git to make use of new git features - GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT: it is hard to upgrade git in Ubuntu 14.04, and if I can avoid it, it would be much better as I want my server to be "standard" (see https://serverfault.com/questions/544156/git-clone-fail-instead-of-prompting-for-credentials)

b. change https to ssh (e.g. git://) - I can not do this either as I am getting a third-party list of https git locations

c. use the 'yes' command in Ubuntu e.g.

```
    yes | git clone ....
```

this does not seem to work

d. pass random strings to the git clone command

```
    echo " " | git clone
```

this does not seem to work either

---

Basically, what I would like to achieve is that if the git clone command is challenged for a password then it just fails and continues to the next ...

Comment: did you look at `expect`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204070/fail-if-a-script-expects-input-or-entering-passwords

Comment: Ok - that looks really promising, but I probably lack the skills to really understand that.  I also want to continue rather than exist the script altogether.... I will have another look and play to see if I can come up with something.... THANK YOU THANK YOU SO MUCH!